# how to get global ip address of the client

Tags: php, ip-address

I tried like this

```
echo "$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']";
```

It showing IP address of the router,

I want get the global IP address of the client using php,can any one tell me how to get.thanks

Comment: You need `REMOTE_ADDR`

Comment: What's the difference between "global IP address" and "router IP address"?!

Answer (score 2):

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

use this